# Nutanix Community Edition: 2-node possible?

Tags: nutanix

Just beginning to explore Nutanix Community Edition, but from my research, it seems that you can either create a single-node or a "3-4 (Max)" node cluster.

Curious as to why a seemingly-useful 2-node cluster wouldn't be an option, if indeed it isn't.

Comment: There's a nice walk thru with performance testing for Nutanix CE. http://www.cultofanarchy.org/perfomance-test-nutanix-4-node-cluste/

Answer (score 1):

With single node you can just "try" their tech w/out things like HA. For properly working HA you have to have odd amount of nodes to keep quorum.